# Migrating BizTalk 2010 source to 2013

Tags: migration, biztalk, biztalk-2013, biztalk-orchestrations

I have the source code of BizTalk 2010 applications that needs to be re-written for BizTalk 2013.

What i am doing so far is that I am creating new BizTalk 2013 project, adding the existing files from 2010 project (schemas maps orchestrations pipelines etc.) and compiling and building the project (fixing the errors on the way).

Is this approach correct?

Will this produce BizTalk 2013 applications?

I am able to deploy new apps to BizTalk 2013 by the way. I have tried looking for migration techniques over the internet but no luck.

Answer (score 3):

No, just make a backup of the entire solution (file copy, branch, label), then open it in Visual Studio 2012 for BizTalk Server 2013 or Visual Studio 2013 for BizTalk Server 2013 R2.

That is the correct approach and I would actually recommend abandon your previous attempt.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to create new projects for 2013 from scratch. If you open Visual Studio Solution file in VS 2013 then it will automatically upgrade to BizTalk 2013 version files. Most of the time this migration will work without any errors.