# Migrating BizTalk 2010 source to 2016

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-2016

Looking at migration to BizTalk 2016 from our existing 2010

The big question ... what is the upgrade process for existing BTS 2010 solutions?

Is it as easy as opening in VS2015? similar to ...  [Migrating BizTalk 2010 source to 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745340/migrating-biztalk-2010-source-to-2013)

Comment: I was seeing some days ago this [video from Sandro Pereira](https://www.biztalk360.com/integrate-2016-resources/new-set-biztalk-server-tips-tricks/) about BizTalk migrations from London Integrate 2016, maybe it's useful to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From 2010, yes, it's pretty much open and migrate.

The most notable change is to compiled xslt which changes some specific behaviors.  So, you will have to test all your maps specifically.  If there is a problem, you can either refactor it or set a flag to use the old interpreted transform.

Comment: In particular the issues listed in Known issues in BizTalk Server 2013 - Known Issues in XSLCompiledTransform  https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/2954101

Comment: Note: Setting the Use Use XSL Transform setting has no effect in Visual Studio, only when it is deployed. See https://cdijkgraaf.wordpress.com/2016/02/27/biztalk-2013-r2-cu2-use-xsl-transform/